# Importance of the cursor in DB2 stored procedure

Tags: db2

I am working on db2 in my project but there is one question that, "Why do we declare cursor in the stored procedure". Can't we write stored procedure in DB2 without declaring a cursor?

Comment: Yes, you can create stored procs without cursors. Is there a problem in your question?

Comment: Thank you for the ans. I am using DB2 connect. Everytime when i make Stored procedure without cursor, it doesn't accept the code without cursor. can u send me one sample stored procedure without cursor?

Answer (score 2):

Stored procedures are flexible and they can perform many tasks. If you want to deal with data you need one of the following things:

- A variable
- A cursor

You can assign the value of a select into a variable, if the result is just one value

```
SET MAX = (SELECT MAX(SALARY) FROM EMP);
```

If you want to deal with multiple values from a result set you need a cursor, in order to fetch each row.

Comment: Thank you for your reply @AngocA. But my question is I am unable to write StoredProcedure without declaring a cursor. So what can i do?my query is select * from EMP; without declaring a cursor, I am unable to write this query in the Stored Procedure.

Comment: Your question is not clear from the point of view of Stored Procedures. What do you want to do with you select * from EMP? scan the values? the column types should be specified in order to fetch the values into variables. * could me one column or 1024 columns?

Comment: My only question is that, Can I write Stored procedure without declaring a cursor? Here I am unable to write SP without declaring cursor

Comment: Sure you can: CREATE PROCEDURE P BEGIN END@